# SELECT query with LIMIT from database column on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
user          messages
+---------+   +----------------+
|id|credit|   |id|user_id| ... |
+---------+   +----------------+
|01| 05   |   |01| 01    | ... |
|02| 01   |   |02| 01    | ... |
|03| 00   |   |03| 01    | ... |
+---------+   |04| 02    | ... |
              |05| 02    | ... |
              |06| 03    | ... |
              +----------------+
```

I need to select **n** messages from *messages* where **n=user.credit**. The query I would like to execute a query like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u JOIN messages m ON u.id = m.user_id LIMIT u.credit 
WHERE user in ...;
```

And should return rows 01, 02, 03, 04 but not 05, 06.

I know I can't write `LIMIT u.credit` but want that behavior, limit the number of messages fetched for each user in function of the value of the credits they have (user 01 whit limit of 5, user 02 with limit of 1 and so on) and I want to fetch all the messages all at once to avoid having to do a COUNT and then a SELECT for each user.

I'm using MySQL with InnoDB

Comment: `u.id == m.user_id` should be `u.id = m.user_id`

Comment: You can only specify a constant literal for `LIMIT`, not an expression.

Comment: Directly in mysql, your best bet is to write a stored procedure that selects the `u.credit` value into a variable, then builds a query-string using that value as the limit and then having the procedure execute that query.

Comment: @SalmanA I know, I'm looking for a workaround, but avoiding making multiple queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution in plain SQL, without using variables:

```
select user.*, messages.*
from user inner join messages
     on user.id=messages.user_id
where (select count(*) from messages m
       where m.user_id=user.id
       and m.id<messages.id)<user.credit
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is going to be slow:

```
SELECT u.*
     , m.*
FROM 
    user AS u 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT m1.*, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM messages m1
        JOIN messages m2
          ON  m2.user_id = m1.user_id 
          AND m2.id <= m1.id
      GROUP BY m1.user_id, m1.id 
    ) m 
      ON  m.user_id = u.id 
      AND m.cnt <= u.credit ;
```

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that in SQL if you are determined to.

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM user u JOIN messages m ON u.id = m.user_id
  inner join user u2 on u2.id <= u.id
WHERE user in ...
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING count(u2.id) < u.credit
```

Comment: It seems good, but MySQL does not allow expressions on the LIMIT clause

Comment: I see that it should be <= instead of <.  I'll edit my answer.